# IDownloadHistoryDatabase - how can I find out the interface definition?

Tags: com, atl

I found out that when cleaning IE download history, an object that implements `IDownloadHistoryDatabase` is created.

Actually the object is being created by calling into **ieproxy.dll** and uses its `IPSFactoryBuffer` implementation.

I have been able to create the object but I can't use it as I don't know the interface definition.

```
CComPtr<IUnknown> spUnk;
spFactory->CreateProxy(0, IID_IDownloadHistoryDatabase, &spProxyBuffer, (void**)&spUnk);
```

I tried querying for `IProvideClassInfo` using `spUnk` but it is not implemented.

Does anybody have this interface definition? or any idea on how to find out the vtable structure for this interface?

Comment: Looks like undocumented internal interface, without public declaration.

Comment: Have you tried to find it using OLEVIEW?